# How to summarize vegetation data of a raster layer within a series of clipped polygons

Tags: arcgis-pro, zonal-statistics, vegetation-index

[image]

I'm trying to analyze how much of the land cover percentage within a series of polygons along a river is Tree Cover.

I made a 5000m buffer around the Columbia River in Washington state, then overlayed a Burned Areas Boundaries Dataset from mtbs.gov on top.

I clipped that to get the burned areas near the river, then overlayed an Existing Vegetation Cover raster layer from landfire.gov.

From there, I ran zonal statistics as Table to summarize the statistics of the vegetation within the burned areas along the river. Then I joined the output table back to that burned area perimeter clip I made.

And yet...I cannot figure out what the statistics from the Zonal Stats tool mean. The original "Existing Vegetation Cover" raster has a "CLASSNAMES" attribute that clearly states what vegetation type I'm looking at, but that attribute column doesn't clearly show up in the output table so I have no idea how to analyze the tree cover.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or if there's another way to get the vegetation data out of these burned areas?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or share demo data?

Comment: Sure! What do you think you need a screenshot of exactly? The data tables?

Okay, I uploaded a screenshot of the Zonal statistics as Table output, the table summarizes the data but doesn't delineate by vegetation type in anyway that I can decipher. None of the numbers relate back to the original raster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone that looked at my question and tried to help.

I spoke with some classmates and they helped me out by telling me about the
"Intersect" and "Extract by Mask" tools. I'm not 100% sure how they work but by using those two tools, I was able to get the results I needed. Hope this helps people in the future!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).